# I have an error in Javascript with an A href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I don't understand why this an issue.
Could someone explain the issue and may be a possible fix.
Thank you.

Error:
XHTML element "a" is not allowed as child of XHTML element "script" in this context

Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
         // Andy Langton's show/hide/mini-accordion - updated 23/11/2009
         // Latest version @ http://andylangton.co.uk/jquery-show-hide

         // this tells jquery to run the function below once the DOM is ready
         $(document).ready(function() {

              // choose text for the show/hide link - can contain HTML (e.g. an image)
              var showText='More Info'; 
              var hideText='Less Info';

              // initialise the visibility check
              var is_visible = false;

              // append show/hide links to the element directly preceding the element with a class of "toggle"
             ***$('.toggle').prev().append(' (<a href="#" class="toggleLink">'+showText+'</a>)');***

             // hide all of the elements with a class of 'toggle'
             $('.toggle').hide();

             // capture clicks on the toggle links
             $('a.toggleLink').click(function() {

                    // switch visibility
                    is_visible = !is_visible;

                   // change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
                   $(this).html( (!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);

                   // toggle the display - uncomment the next line for a basic "accordion" style
                   //$('.toggle').hide();$('a.toggleLink').html(showText);
                   $(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle('slow');

                   // return false so any link destination is not followed
                   return false;

               });
         });
    <script>
```

Comment: You can't put an anchor tag inside of a script tag. Kinda self explanatory.

Comment: Convert your XHTML into HTML5?

Comment: Can you post the html around what has the class="toggle"?

Comment: Try splitting up the tag: `$('.toggle').prev().append(' (<'+'a href="#" class="toggleLink"'+'>'+showText+'</'+'a>)');`

Comment: Where is this error coming from?  Is it from some validator?  It appears to me that your validator just isn't smart enough.  Any HTML you want is allow inside a javascript string.  This error seems bogus to me.

Comment: error with your code is  the content of element must consisted of well-formed character or markup

Comment: I am getting the error form NetBeans

Comment: It's a bogus error.  If you put your script in a dedicated .js file instead of embedded in your HTML file, then NetBeans probably won't get confused.

Comment: Blazemonger's code suggestion (their 2nd comment) will probably hide the `<a>` tag from netbeans.

Comment: jfriend's right; provided there isn't a syntax leak somewhere in the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between HTML and XHTML. In XHTML, scripts don't have a CDATA content type: the contents is treated exactly the same as any other element. It's not just a NetBeans issue.

So, there are several solutions:

- Put the script in a separate file, so that its contents will not be mangled by the XML parser. This is the best solution, as it doesn't have any drawbacks. It works for HTML and XHTML.
- Make sure the contents don't contain any `<` or `&` signs. Also make sure that editing the script will not introduce `<` or `&` signs later on. Replace them with their entity references: `&lt;` and `&amp;` respectively.
- If the script doesn't contain `]]>`, you can put the whole content in a `<![CDATA[` .. `]]>` block. This may even work in HTML in some browsers, but as `<![CDATA[` is not formally defined as part of the HTML standard, this method is (officially) not HTML compatible.